# how to integrate my muse js into my ionic 3 project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

( Am trying to integrate the below code into my ionic3 project the music will play but the skin image will not display. Any help)

**Note:** I want to add a live streaming fm station into my `ionic 3` app am using `muse javascript API`.

```
   <pre>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://hosted.muses.org/mrp.js">
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
           MRP.insert({
           'url':'http://104.247.79.188:8000/kapitalfm929',
           'lang':'en',
           'codec':'mp3',
           'volume':100,
           'autoplay':true,
          'jsevents':true,
          'buffering':0,
          'title':'KFM',
          'welcome':'Station',
          'wmode':'transparent',
          'skin':'repvku-100',
          'width':100,
          'height':25
           });
          </script>

<pre>
```

Comment: Can you tell us more details about your use case?

Comment: This is a Horrible way of doing Ionic 3 app.Please tell us what you need to do.then we'll suggest you a proper way for doing that.

Comment: ok, I want to add a livestreaming fm station into my ionic 3 app am using muse javascript API " https://hosted.muses.org/mrp.js"

Comment: Hope you have fm `url` no?

Comment: yes i do "http://104.247.79.188:8000/"

Comment: Please use this plugin for Ionic 3+ [https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a basic demo of Radio Player with `play` and `pause` buttons as shown below.

*radio-player.ts*

```
export class RadioPlayer {
  url:string;
  stream:any;
  promise:any;

 constructor() {
   this.url = "http://akalmultimedia.net:8000/GDNSLDH";
   this.stream = new Audio(this.url);
 };

 play() {
   this.stream.play();
   this.promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
     this.stream.addEventListener('playing', () => {
       resolve(true);
     });

     this.stream.addEventListener('error', () => {
       reject(false);
     });
   });

  return this.promise;
};

pause() {
  this.stream.pause();
};

}
```

*.html*

```
<ion-navbar *navbar> 
  <ion-title> Radio Player </ion-title> 
</ion-navbar> 

<ion-content class="home"> 
  <button dark (click)="play()"> 
    <ion-icon name="play"></ion-icon>
  </button> 
  <button dark (click)="pause()"> 
    <ion-icon name="pause"></ion-icon>
  </button> 
</ion-content>
```

You can read more about [**this here**](https://inders.in/blog/2016/02/12/creating-radio-player-with-ionic-2-and-html5/).But that was `Ionic 2` app.So use it properly on you `Ionic 3` app.

Comment: Please use this plugin for Ionic 3+ [https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media/]